# What event is triggered when an arrow or other icon is clicked to expand a branch of a tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I know how to trap clicking on a node:

```
    // Define action when a node was clicked.
    $('#mytree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
      // do whatever
    });
```

But I can't figure out which event is triggered when clicking an icon to expand a branch of a tree.  I have reviewed the list of events in the documentation, but none stands out as self-evident.  I tried:

```
// Define action when a node is expanded.
$('#mytree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    // do whatever
});
```

but it didn't get triggered.  I also tried:

```
// Define action when a node is expanded.
$('#mytree').on("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    /do whatever
});
```

but that gets triggered for each node when the tree is loaded, not when a specific node is clicked to expose its children.

Comment: I know the events are listed, but as many have mentioned their documentation is thin and it is not clear which is the appropriate one.

Comment: Add them all with a unique console log message and see which one(s) get triggered

Comment: FYI, the answer, as provided by rpo, click.jstree, is not one of the events listed in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't add this as comment, have u tried `click.jstree` ?

```
$('#mytree').on("click.jstree", function (e, data) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: By the way, how did you know that was the answer given that click.jstree is not listed in the docs as an event?

Comment: I had to go through the [source] (
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/1ada416cc0426a7799ac210ba37f20343fcae4f8/src/jstree.js#L746) sometime back for the same scenario.

Comment: Because of the lack of documentation on click.jstree I'm having trouble determing the node id of the node whose arrow was clicked.  Did you find that, too?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
$('#JSTree').on("click.jstree", ".jstree-ocl", function (e)  {
    if ((this).parentElement.classList.contains('jstree-closed'))
    {selectedNode = ($(this).nextAll(".jstree-anchor").attr("id"))
     var node = $('#JSTree').jstree("get_node", selectedNode);
     alert(node.text)
     alert(node.id)}
})
```